# Can it be replaced with the relative pronoun that?

Tags: grammar

(1) I called out to the student who was turning around to see me.

(2) I called out to the student, who was turning around to see me

I understand the comma before who makes a difference in the meanings of the two sentences.  I also understand that the relative pronoun who can be replaced with the relative pronoun "that"  in sentence (1).

But what about the relative pronoun who with a comma?  Can it be replaced with the relative pronoun that?   I think it cannot be replaced.

Could you help me clarify it?  Thank you always.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct (in your last suggestion): *that* may replace the relative *who* in a restrictive relative clause (without a comma); but it may not do so in a non-restrictive relative clause (with a comma).

Comment: Yes, but there is a preference for "who" when the relativised element is subject, as it is here.

Comment: I wasn't convinced that that was so, @BillJ, but the iWeb corpus seems to bear you out: 187 000 instances of "man who [verb]" against 19 000 of "man that [verb]".

Answer (score 0):

In your example, using a comma is good

> I called out to the student**,** who was turning around to see me.

to separate the subordinate clause.

Your alternative sentence

> I called out to the student, **that** was turning around to see me.

would be understood, but "***that***" is usually used for *things* whereas "***who***" / "***whom***" are used for *people*.

> The picture **that** hung on the wall...
>   The cat **that** sat on the chair...
>   The boy **who** watched TV...
>   The girl **whom** I kissed...

Comment: This may be a UK/NAm difference, but I have no problem with _that_ for people. Also, you haven't answered the question.

Comment: Supplementary (non-defining) _that_ relatives are virtually unheard of, and only marginally acceptable.